# Due-diligence behind discount window lending

Tags: federal-reserve, discount-rate

Its clear the Federal reserve is doing risk assessments at the discount window since they separate credit into primary and secondary.

I'm curious how secondary credit risk is handled. Given that insolvent banks should generally be allowed to fail, do they make solvency a (loose?) criteria for secondary credit? Or do they give out secondary credit easily and use collateral to mitigate risk?